# How can I repair a radiator bleed valve that fell out?

Tags: radiator, valve

I over-tightened the bleed valve on the radiator and it fell out! It seems to look like a screw but I can't seem to get it re-attached, luckily it's locked so not leaking.

I can't see well enough to try and get it back on as a big cabinet is in the way. But I was wondering if it does actually screw back on or if I've snapped it off and it's permanently broken?

[image: Hole where the radiator bleed valve should be]

Comment: Any chance you can post a few pics of the broken(?) valve and the radiator?

Comment: Twisted off the stem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is snapped off. You're OK until you need to bleed again. Then you will need to gain enough access to drill a small hole into the broken screw. Once a screw extractor is inserted into the hole, the rest of the screw should come out and you can place a new vent screw in it's place. These screws do not need to be super tight, firmly snugged should do it. At least now you know how much is too much.

Comment: Cheers, I'll be sure to do that when i have the time. Any ideas on where i can get a new screw?

Comment: Ah, there's the rub. It may have a particular shape on the end, and you'd have to remove it to see what it is. Not to mention compatible threads, though the broken off piece may have enough thread for an ID. I've no idea how 'standard' these things are. You may be able to go to a good plumbing shop and ask for a radiator bleed screw and get the right one. Or not, I've no idea, sorry.